# how can I make the order of x axis in a correct way

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been struggling with a plot for sometimes

```
df<- structure(list(x = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12"), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("my_rep1a", "you_rep2a"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(-7.70891, 0.9699727, 3.644688, 2.810303, -4.579114, 
    -6.57653, -1.938455, 3.201102, 4.951608, -1.263285, -0.9699727, 
    3.675765, -2.269753, -1.255846, 1.336035, -0.7997434, -0.4488655, 
    0.4488655, 0.7199451, 2.504063, 0.7398947, 0.6827841, -3.841076, 
    -3.018841)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

SO I plot it like this

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = value,
          group = variable, color = variable)) + geom_line()
```

it does not give me the right order in x axis

[image]

I did try to change my x to character as `df$x <- as.character(df$x)` but did not help . The same when I convert it to integer

if I use integer or numeric, it gives me different numbers in x axis which I cannot know if it plots it correctly or not

[image]

Comment: try `df$x <- as.numeric(df$x)` (or better `df$x <- as.integer(df$x)`) - the current order is correct in alphanumeric character terms

Comment: @dww I did that but instead uses 1, 2, 3, 4 for the axis It gives me whatever range it wants , sorry for stupid question. When I use even `xlim(1, 12)` it does not give me the x numbers , I show it above

Comment: add `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:12)` or similar

Comment: @dww Yes that gives me the right answer, thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to get acquainted with package `stringr`, function `str_sort`. Set argument `numeric = TRUE` to sort characters numerically.

```
lvls <- stringr::str_sort(unique(df$x), numeric = TRUE)
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels = lvls)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = value,
                      group = variable, color = variable)) + 
  geom_line()
```

[image]